# Subprocess not working correctly

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this code that I need to run a subprocess with and print off the output of whats in the command window.

```
import subprocess

msprompt = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild.exe'
path = "C:/Users/bgb/Documents/Brent/Code/Visual Studio/tree.DataManagement.UnitTests./tree.DataManagement.UnitTests.vbproj"

def command(msprompt, openFile):

    for line in finalPathList:


        p = subprocess.Popen([msprompt, path], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        for line in p.stdout.readlines():
            print line,
        retval = p.wait()
```

When I run this in the compiler it doesnt work, it spits out this message:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: "C:/Users/bgb/Documents/Brent/Code/Visual Studio/tree.FormControls.UnitTests./tree.FormControls.UnitTests.vbproj"
```

However, if I open up the command window completely seperate, and I copy over and paste `msprompt` and then I copy over `path` and paste it into the command window and hit enter, it works perfectly, does anyone know what I'm messing up in my `command` function??

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, there's a few things here that make me think this isn't actually your code (`openFile`, `finalPathList`...), but I'd start by trying to standardize your path structure.  You're on Windows, so you should probably stick with back slashes in path literals if you aren't passing them through anything in the `os` library, and also consistently escape them.

Comment: preferably use raw strings r'string\with\backspace', as you then don't have to escape the path separator.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl Or that.  Though I find that using raw strings can get confusing in larger programs, since you almost invariably end up having to work with both at the same time.

Comment: This is my code, I just didn't include every function I have, I just tried to condense it so it would be easier to follow for you guys haha, I'm going to try and reverse the direction of the slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your path format is incorrect, it should be with two back slashes `\\` and not forward slashes `/`.

For debugging purposes, try using `os.path.exists(path)`, to first make sure the path is correct. You can then use `os.path.join` to fix your path (docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)).

Comment: Isn't / a slash an \ a backslash?

Comment: @enginefree It's called backslash. Forward slash is the other one (/).

Comment: Changing the direction of the slashes doesn't matter, it still doesnt work, and plus when I try it directly in the command line prompt it works regardless of what direction the slashes are, so Idk... :(

Comment: @bbesase dos the path exist (try using `os.path.exists(path)`).

Comment: @enginefree It returned False, so no I guess they don't...How come when I hardcode the path in it works and when I try passing it in it bugs out, shouldnt it be the same thing?

Comment: @bbesase to answer that question, I need to know what the exact path is, drag the file into cmd copy the path.

Comment: @enginefree `"C:\Users\Bgb\Documents\Brent\Code\Visual Studio\tree.DataManagement.UnitTests\tree.DataManagement.UnitTests.vbproj"`